# Using MySQL, always have the expected number of elements in a dataset by filling the remaining with previous written data

Tags: mysql, sql

is it possible to always respect an expected number of element constraint by filling the remaining of a SQL dataset with previous written data, keeping the data insertion in order? Using MySQL?

**Edit**
In a web store, I always want to show n elements. I update the show elements every w seconds and I want to loop indefinitely.

By example, using table myTable:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
|  3 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
+----+
```

Something like

```
SELECT id FROM myTable WHERE id > 3 ORDER BY id ALWAYS_RETURN_THIS_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS 5
```

would actually return (where ALWAYS_RETURN_THIS_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENTS doesn't exist)

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  4 |
|  5 |
|  4 |
+----+
```

Comment: Although I find the question highly unusual, I see nothing about it that deserves a down vote.

Comment: I don't understand why my question has a down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange need.  Here is a method:

```
select id
from (SELECT id
      FROM myTable
      WHERE id > 3
      ORDER BY id
      LIMIT 5
     ) t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n
order by n.n, id
limit 5;
```

You may need to extend the list of numbers in `n` to be sure you have enough rows for the final `limit`.

Comment: Two words for the requirement this statement satisfies: *biz* and *arre*.

Comment: If you read my edit about the use case, maybe it will be easier for you to answer :)

Comment: Using a query like this to satisfy the use case is very strange indeed. The use case sounds much more like a presentation issue than it does a data retrieval issue; mucking up the query that retrieves rows to make it return exactly N rows by repeating rows is just not the right way to satisfy the use case.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not what `LIMIT` does. The `LIMIT` clause is applied as the last step in the statement execution, after aggregation, after the HAVING clause, and after ordering.

I can't fathom a use case that would require the type of functionality you describe.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

The query that Gordon Linoff provided will return the specified result, as long as there is at least one row in `myTable` that satisfies the predicate. Otherwise, it will return zero rows.

---

Here's the EXPLAIN output for Gordon's query:

```
id select_type  table            type  key     rows Extra 
-- ------------ ---------------- ----- ------- ---- -------------------------------
 1 PRIMARY      <derived2>       ALL              5 Using temporary; Using filesort
 1 PRIMARY      <derived3>       ALL              5 Using join buffer
 3 DERIVED                                          No tables used
 4 UNION                                            No tables used
 5 UNION                                            No tables used
 6 UNION                                            No tables used
 7 UNION                                            No tables used
   UNION RESULT <union3,4,5,6,7> ALL 
 2 DERIVED      myTable          range PRIMARY   10 Using where; Using index
```

---

Here's the EXPLAIN output for the original query:

```
id select_type table             type  key     rows Extra 
-- ----------- ----------------- ----- ------- ---- -------------------------------
 1 SIMPLE      myTable           range PRIMARY   10 Using where; Using index
```

---

It just seems like it would be a **whole lot more efficient** to reprocess the resultset from the original query, if that resultset contains fewer than five (and more than zero) rows. (When that number of rows goes from 5 to 1,000 or 150,000, it would be even stranger.)

The code to get multiple copies of rows from a resultset is quite simple: fetch the rows, and if the end of the result set is reached before you've fetched five (or N) rows, then just reset the row pointer back to the first row, so the next fetch will return the first row again. In PHP using `mysqli`, for example, you could use:

```
$result->data_seek(0);
```

Or, for those still using the deprecated `mysql_` interface:

```
mysql_data_seek($result,0);
```

But if you're returning only five rows, it's likely you aren't even looping through the result at all, and you already stuffed all the rows into an array. Just loop back through the beginning of the array.

For MySQL interfaces that don't support a scrollable cursor, we'd just store the whole resultset and process it multiple times.  With Perl DBI, using the `fetchall_arrayref`, with JDBC (which is going to store the whole result set in memory anyway without special settings on the connection), we'd store the resultset as an object.

Bottom line, squeezing this requirement (to produce a resultset of exactly five rows) back to the database server, and pulling back duplicate copies of a row and/or storing duplicate copies of a row in memory just seems like the wrong way to satisfy the use case. (If there's rationale for storing duplicate copies of a row in memory, then that can be achieved without pulling duplicate copies of rows back from the database.)

It's just very odd that you say you're using/implementing a "circular buffer", but that you choose not to "circle" back around to the beginning of a resultset which contains fewer than five rows, and instead need to have MySQL return you duplicate rows. Just very, very strange.

Comment: I just edit my question, I just want to respect a number of element. I want to use it in a circular buffer.

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard, if the buffer's circular, wouldn't two elements circle just as well?

Comment: A circular buffer? You mean like a round wastebasket?

Comment: Excuse me, me question is not really clear. in a web store, I always want to show n elements. I update the show elements every n seconds and I want to loop indefinitely.

Comment: @Pier-Alexandre Bouchard: your use case sounds more like a presentation issue than it does a data retrieval issue; that is, you don't really need for MySQL to return exactly N rows. If MySQL returns fewer than N rows, then just repeat the rows that MySQL *does* return however many times you need. You needn't muck up the query with the logic to do that.

Comment: Maybe the use case I gave sounds like a presentation issue, but in the real case, it's not. The web store example was just to figure out a viable example to build the query.

Comment: @Pier-Alexandre Bouchard: The query that Gordon Linoff provided will return the specified result (as long as there is at least one row that satisfies the predicates). But its very strange that you mention a "circular buffer", yet you can't make your code "circle" back to the first row in a resultset that has less than five (and more than zero) rows. Just very, very strange.